# Is there a way to modify a RLMObject without persisting it?

Tags: realm

I am quite new to Realm, contemplating to move away from a CoreData stack in favor of it in a specific project, since I mostly only need local storage - Realm feels like a perfect match at least on paper. The issue I am facing is that I can't find a way to modify a subclassed RLMObject retrieved from RLMResults without a write transaction. I do understand where this is coming from but in my specific case this is an issue - the user can freely modify an object and then save or discard the changes. It doesn't feel right to keep Realm up to date and then rollback if the users cancels out of his editing and all workarounds feel dirty to me. Is there a clever way to modify the object freely and only once the user decides to save his changes hit createOrUpdate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The design pattern you're looking for here is likely to "detach" the Realm object so you can modify it in-memory as a "standalone object" (not tied to any Realm). You can do this by initializing a new object from the values of the old object:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSInteger identifier;
@property NSString *name;
@end
@implementation Dog
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"identifier";
}
@end

// Editing screen...

Dog *standaloneDog = [[Dog alloc] initWithValue:persistedDog];
standaloneDog.name = @"Fido"; // <- no write transaction necessary

// On save:

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    // updates the persisted dog with the standalone dog's new values.
    [Dog createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:standaloneDog];
}];

// Nothing to do on cancel since the object was standalone.
```

Please refer to Realm's Objective-C docs on "Updating Objects" for more information: https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#updating-objects

Comment: Aha! This is exactly what I've been missing, thanks!